# Having issue in javascript code. light box does not open second time

Tags: javascript

I have a code which opens lightbox when user click a link. What it does it opens lightbox, then when user clicks on `overlay` it closes or hides overlay and lightbox. But when user click on link again to open lightbox again then it does not open. Here is my code

```
var el = document.getElementById('element');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
            el.innerHTML = '<p><a id="clickme" href="#">Click me</a></p>';
            document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (overlay) {
                overlay.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="overlay" style="display:block;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>'+document.body.innerHTML;                   
            }
                document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe id="frame" style="position:absolute;display:block;z-index:101;width:50%;height:50%;margin:10% 20%;border:10px solid #ccc;border-radius:10px;" src="http://www.example.com/"></iframe>'+document.body.innerHTML;

                document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
```

How can I open this lightbox again when user clicks link second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `style` to `display:none` on close but clicking the link doesn't change the `display` property. Effect: the box stays invisible.

Simple solution: add `display:block` or whatever you need there to the opening function.

In addition: your opening function will create a new element **each** time it is executed. You could add a test to prevent that:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
if(overlay){
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    //create box
}
```

Comment: I updated my code above. Please see it. I added display:block to overlay and iframe. Still the same problem.

Comment: Try adding the box only once (see my example in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as you edit the DOM by adding or replacing document.body.innerHTML, the event on your element (your a href) will no longer exist. you would need to append the event again after you performed document.body.innerHTML.

Comment: Don't rewrite the body html but append the new element. That should do the trick.